# Get concrete property that implements type

Tags: c#, reflection

Given the following classes

```
public Foo 
{
  public Foo() {
    this.Bar = new Bar();
  }

  public IBar Bar{ get; set;}
}

public Bar : IBar
{
 // implemented properties

}
```

How can I get the concrete implementation of the property *Bar* on *Foo* using reflection?

```
instance.GetType().GetProperty("Bar").PropertyType
```

Yields the interface only.

Comment: Unless you also get the actual value of the property `Bar`, I'm pretty sure you can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to get type that implements IBar you should get it's value and take the type:

```
var type = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Bar").GetValue(instance,null).GetType()
```

Comment: Since .NET 4.5 (from 2012), there is a new [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx) so you can drop the ugly `,null` part.

Comment: (Of course, without reflection one can do `instace.Bar.GetType()`, but that was possibly not what @JamesSouth asked.)